# product method in shuffle deck of cards

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Python program to shuffle a deck of card

# importing modules
import itertools, random

# make a deck of cards
deck = list(itertools.product(range(1,14),['Spade','Heart','Diamond','Club']))

# shuffle the cards
random.shuffle(deck)

# draw five cards
print("You got:")
for i in range(5):
   print(deck[i][0], "of", deck[i][1])
```

I can't understand how is the program working here. Especially in line 5 and line 11.

Comment: See the official documentation for [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and itertools [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fifth line is making a list of  (x,y) pairs for every value from 1 to 14, and for every suit.

The output for deck (line 5)

```
[(1, 'Spade'), (1, 'Heart'), (1, 'Diamond'), (1, 'Club'), (2, 'Spade'), (2, 'Heart'), (2, 'Diamond'), (2, 'Club'), (3, 'Spade'), (3, 'Heart'), (3, 'Diamond'), (3, 'Club'), (4, 'Spade'), (4, 'Heart'), (4, 'Diamond'), (4, 'Club'), (5, 'Spade'), (5, 'Heart'), (5, 'Diamond'), (5, 'Club'), (6, 'Spade'), (6, 'Heart'), (6, 'Diamond'), (6, 'Club'), (7, 'Spade'), (7, 'Heart'), (7, 'Diamond'), (7, 'Club'), (8, 'Spade'), (8, 'Heart'), (8, 'Diamond'), (8, 'Club'), (9, 'Spade'), (9, 'Heart'), (9, 'Diamond'), (9, 'Club'), (10, 'Spade'), (10, 'Heart'), (10, 'Diamond'), (10, 'Club'), (11, 'Spade'), (11, 'Heart'), (11, 'Diamond'), (11, 'Club'), (12, 'Spade'), (12, 'Heart'), (12, 'Diamond'), (12, 'Club'), (13, 'Spade'), (13, 'Heart'), (13, 'Diamond'), (13, 'Club')]
```

Line 11 is simply getting the values from the list using `i` to get the first five (after it is shuffled) and then using `[0]` to get the value of the card, and then using`[1]` to get the suit of the card

The output from line 11:

```
You got:
3 of Spade
8 of Spade
12 of Heart
4 of Spade
4 of Diamond
```